# Which type of ship does this engine belong to?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, there is a scene in the Rebel base on Yavin where we can see blind warrior Chirrut Îmwe and mercenary Baze Malbus sitting/standing near to what seems to be a L4 fusial thrust. I have been going through quite a few detailed ship's cross sections and blueprints but I couldn't find a ship possessing an engine like this, thus, to which ship belongs this engine?

I want to clarify that something that make my question a bit difficult to answer is the fact that most of the engines are enclosed/covered with a housing that it is not commonly removed or bled through to show the engine and other internals.

[image: Rogue One Still movie image 1]

[image: Rogue One Still movie image 2]

Here a picture showing engine internals of a Kotobukiya Cross section 3-D X-Wing.

[image: X-Wing section from Kotobukiya Cross section 3-D X-Wing]

Comment: Think it looks like part of a Y-wing's engine. Has the domed housing and some other details that say "Y-wing" to me.

Comment: Generic Engine Part Prop #37

Comment: I used to work doing maintenance for aero-derivative gas generators in oil rigs (retired now). This one barely looks like the venerable General Electric LM2500.

Comment: This is an obvious homework question from a Rebel Flight Engineer's apprenticeship application; e.g. What ships use an *'4L4 fusial thrust'* in their propulsion system?